# What's the equivalent of TagBuilder in Blazor?

Tags: blazor

I'm trying to build some markups that depends on some logic. I remember that I used to use the [TagBuilder Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/views/using-the-tagbuilder-class-to-build-html-helpers-cs) for that. I tried to use it then I notice the **using System.Web.Mvc** it relies on.

Is there a similar class that I can use in a blazor application?

Thanks for helping.

EDIT,

I was actually trying to build this [treeview](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_treeview) in Blazor. With hard-coded html, it's straightforward. However, when I need to build it in razor with data from the API, using a utility class, such as **TagBuilder** is helpful.

Comment: Blazor is all about Components - you should be able to write whatever you need as a component.

Comment: I know that. However, `TagBuilder Class` allow you to generate HTML using `C#`. That's really handy for case where you need to use some complex logic to generate markups.

Comment: You can build a RenderFragment with a RenderTreeBuilder  but it does go against the grain of Blazor. You can use complex logic in normal Razor syntax, that tree doesn't look to daunting.

Comment: A tree view is quite simple with components. You have just two components to write (you can do it with just one but most people tend to use two). The main tree view has a tree node and the tree node has any number of child tree nodes. All nodes can be generated at runtime from a data source. There are many examples on GitHub like the one here ( https://github.com/FritzAndFriends/BlazorWebFormsComponents/tree/dev/src/BlazorWebFormsComponents ). My  point is, there are no tag helpers in Blazor, just components.

Comment: There are no taghelpers. Perhaps you need to use Render Fragments

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I took a look at the `RenderTreeBuilder`, I don't think it's a good idea to go that route.

Comment: @MisterMagoo, I'll take a look at the implementation on the link you provided.